# NSTimer or pausing operation?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nstimer

Fistly i'm fairly new to programming in general. And very new to Objective C and IOS programming. This is just a practice programming I'm writing to learn with.

What its basically does is this :

The computer chooses a number of times to attack and then randomly choses to a number between 1 and 4 or 0 and 3 (really doesn't matter). It does this each time it goes through the for loop.

What i'm trying to accomplish is this :

If the computer picks 0 then it highlights the appropriate button and makes it active for the user to interact with, but they only have a certain amount of time to press said button. The timer is calls a function that unhighlights the button and makes in inactive.

All this works but it all happens at the same time. If the computer attacks three times all three buttons are highlighted and activated at the same time and then made inactive at the same time. I want to make the program pause for the length of the timer giving the player that amount of time to push the button. I can't figure this part out.  I thought of using a while loop that kicks out when a button is pushed or when the timer calls the function but that just makes it get stuck in the while loop. I have shown this in the first if statement.

Again please keep it simple because i'm newish to programming. Thanks

```
if(theEnemy.attackingOrBlocking == 1)
{
    int whereAttack;
    int numberOfAttacks = 3; //theEnemy.numOfAttacks;
    for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfAttacks; i++)
    {
        whereAttack = theEnemy.attackButton;
        if (whereAttack == 0) 
        {
            while (buttonPushed == NO)
            {
                [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5f target:self selector:@selector(timerCallback) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

                lowAttackBlock.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                lowAttackBlock.highlighted = YES;
            }

        }
        if (whereAttack == 1)
        {
                [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5f target:self selector:@selector(timerCallback) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

                leftAttackBlock.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                leftAttackBlock.highlighted = YES;

        }
        if (whereAttack == 2)
        {
                [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5f target:self selector:@selector(timerCallback) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

                rightAttackBlock.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                rightAttackBlock.highlighted = YES;

        }
        if (whereAttack == 3)
        {
                [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5f target:self selector:@selector(timerCallback) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

                highAttackBlock.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                highAttackBlock.highlighted = YES;
        }
        if (myCharacter.block != whereAttack)
        {
            myCharacter.health -= 10;
            [yourHealth setText:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",myCharacter.health]];
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Launching a timer is an Asynchrone operation, so it won't stop the normal flow of your application, so if you are in a for loop that launch 3 timer, the for loop will completely execute before the first timer will call you back.

A way do to this would be to cache the number of hit in an instance variable that you would decrease by one each time you are calling a timer.

So you launch a a sequence of 3 attacks, you set the `remainingAttack` instance variable to 3, call a method `performAttack` that will check if there is attacks left to do, if there is you perform the attack (or you want to perform it from the timer call back), decrease the number of attack by 1 (or from the timer call back), launch a timer.
In the timer callBack do your logic, then call your `performAttack` again as the last action of your timer.
That would be the basic logic I can think of right now, you will have to adapt it to your personal need, and there is probably a better solution. but that is one.